# Insert String to linked list does not work

Tags: c, linked-list

When I want to insert String to linked list it shows

> incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter
>   of type 'const char   *'; take the address with & [-Wint-conversion]
>    in the line  `strcpy(current->name,name1);`

Here the code

```
node* new_node(char name1,float num) {
  node *current = malloc(sizeof(node));
  if (current == NULL) return NULL;
  strcpy(current->name,name1);
  current->score = num;
  current->next = NULL;
  return current;
}

struct NODE {
    char name[40];
    float score;
    struct NODE *next;
};
```

Could any one help me on that, I search and tried many ways but did not work.

Comment: `char name1` --> `char *name1` (name is an array of chars, not a single `char`)

Comment: @ Keine Lust : I did it but show error "conflicting types for 'new_node"

Comment: Why are you using `NODE` (upper) and `node` (lower)?

Comment: change the defintion in a h file also

Comment: What compiler is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function definition, `node* new_node(char name1, float num)` you are getting a single char, what you want is a pointer to location where the string is actually stored, so change this definition to node* `new_node(char *name1, float num)`

Also change in a place where you might have declared the function, i.e., in a `h` file or in the beginning of this file.

Comment: Also change in a place where you might have declared the function, i.e., in a h file or in the beginning of this file, other wise post exact compilation error dump

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a homework problem.

Anyways, there are several issues with your code such as

- Wrong order of declaration (`struct NODE` is declared after it is being used). This may not be in the actual code, but if it is, do correct it.
- Wrong type being used. You are using `node` instead of `NODE` in the function `new_node`. That itself should throw a compiler error.
- Using copy-by-value doesn't work for array in C. The function takes the first argument of type `char`. If you want only a char to be copied, then take its address as suggested. Otherwise, change type to `char*`

  ```
   strcpy(current->name, &name1); \\ if name1 is of type char
   strcpy(current->name, name1);  \\ if name1 is of type char*
  ```
- Using `strcpy` instead of `strncpy`. The former suffers from a potential buffer overflow.

http://codepad.org/WPR5Piye